# How to rotate spiral curve by 90 degrees such that the curve starts on the positive Y-axis?

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

[The spiral curve that needs to be rotated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NykUW.png)
The curve has an initial radius of 0.2 and a final radius of 1.0. It rotates for 2 revolutions and has to start at the positive y-axis and end at the positive y-axis too. My current equations are:
$$
\begin{cases}
x&=-(0.8u+0.2) \cos(4\pi ~ u) \\
y&=~(0.8u+0.2) \sin(4\pi ~ u)
\end{cases}
\qquad
u \in [0,1]
$$

Comment: Hint: try switching the expressions for $x$ and $y$ and then some sign change. So copy-paste the expression for $y$ to the expression for $x$ and vice-versa. Report back with your findings.

Comment: Ah thank you. x=(0.8*u+0.2)*sin(4*pi* u); y=(0.8*u+0.2)*cos(4*pi* u);